# Doctrine select many from the one (many-to-one unidirectional (different bundles))

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, many-to-one

Working on a legacy project which restricts the options available, has left me in a situation where I need to solve the following problem, ideally with doctrine.

I have two entities in different bundles that have a unidirectional many-to-one link.

BundleA has dependency on BundleB and the entities are linked similar to this:

BundleA/Entity/TheMany:

```
/**
 * @var TheOne $theOne
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BundleB\Entity\TheOne")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="theone_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 * 
 */
private $theOne;
```

From BundleB I now need to select all TheOne entities, and for each I need all of the TheMany entities.

The query also needs to be sortable on any property of TheOne entity, or the count of related TheMany entities.

It is fairly simple in Doctrine to build a query which brings back all TheOne entities and one of TheMany for each... however I am having some difficulty coming up with a Doctrine query that will bring back all of the related TheMany entities rather than just one.

I was hoping someone might have encountered a similar issue and therefore have some insight?

This may not have been explained clearly enough, in which case please direct me to explain further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I was able to achieve what I needed by using GROUP_CONCAT (which required inclusion of https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions).

The query looks something like this:

```
    $queryBuilder->select(
        'to,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tm.id SEPARATOR \',\') as theManyIds, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT tm.id) as HIDDEN theManyCount'
    )
        ->from('BundleB\Entity\TheOne', 'to')
        ->leftJoin(
            'BundleA\Entity\TheMany',
            'tm',
            Join::WITH,
            'to.id = tm.theOne'
        )
        ->groupBy('to.id')
        ->orderBy($sortString, $direction)
        ->setFirstResult($start)
        ->setMaxResults($limit);
```

I compromised by accepting the consequences of linking the two bundles - however that could have been avoided by making use of Native SQL and Result Set Mapping (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html).

Answer (score 0):

So what you are trying to do is to get all the ones and for each one find all the many. But you want to put all the many in one array or you want to create an array of array for the entities ? (what i did here)

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$theones = $em->getRepository('BundleA:theOne')
    ->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->OrderBy(//your ordering)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getArrayResult()

$theManies = [];

for($theones as $theOne){
    $theManies [] = $em->getRepository('BunbleB:theMany')
        ->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->Where('p.theOne = :theOne')
        ->setParameter('theOne', $theOne)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getArrayResult();
     $finalOnes[$theOne->getId()] = sizeof($theManies)
}

asort($finalOnes);
return array_keys($finalOnes);
```

Comment: Something like that, but there are two problems with this approach, the first is that I need to order the list of TheOne by the number of "TheMany" entities associated with any given TheOne entity. The other issue is that BundleA has not visibility of BundleB. I cannot introduce this link because it is a circular dependency. BundleA requires BundleB but BundleB does not require BundleA (and I cannot add it as a requirement due to circular dependency issues with things like composer).  In reality the two bundles are co-dependent and should be merged, but I can't to do this for various reasons.

Comment: Another point is that it doesn't matter for the purposes of this task if I get the actual hydrated TheMany entities, I actually only need a comma delimited list of the IDs.  I feel I may have to resort to SQL instead of DQL.

Comment: Ok first, if i get what you are asking right i change the code so what you are gonna have there is a list of TheOne order by the number of many they are linked to

Comment: but I dont understand why BundleB shouldn't be recognize. If you just add `use Path\of\BundleB;` this could should work.

Comment: BundleB cannot be included as a requirement for BundleA, because BundleB is already a requirement for BundleA. I cannot introduce a circular dependency, moreover it would be bad practice to add coupling between these two bundles (although as stated they should be the same bundle).  In the application this is not a problem, because both bundles are always present in practice, however for automated testing each bundle must must be able to pass it's full suite of tests as a stand-alone bundle (plus any dependancies).